# PHP 5.3.2, Where do I find php5apache2_2.dll?

Tags: php, apache2

I'm upgrading my local version of PHP to 5.3.2, on Windows.  I'm running Apache 2.2 right now.

I've downloaded the zipped VC6 version of PHP from here: http://windows.php.net/download/

To my dismay, there's no php5apache2_2.dll file anywhere in the ZIP, and unfortunately Google is no help.  I don't understand how anybody manages to get PHP working if there is no .dll available in the ZIP contents.  Why would they not include this essential file, and why is there nowhere to download it?

It has me a bit flustered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind.  I downloaded the non thread safe version instead of the thread safe version.

Comment: That may be true, but a little more explanation would go a long way... E.g. what's the difference between thread-safe and non-thread-safe; and when should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 21):

php5apache2_2.dll only can be found on **thread safe** version.

Comment: That may be true, but a little more explanation would go a long way...
E.g. what's the difference between thread-safe and non-thread-safe; and when should one be used over the other?