# php dll cannot be loaded into server when using apachelounge VC14 build and php.net VC11 build

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am following this [great post](https://superuser.com/questions/748117/how-to-manually-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows)

Version details;

Apache 2.4.16
   php 5.6.11
   mysql community installer 5.6.25

Directory structure:

C:
     server
       Every setup goes here

Windows System - 7 - 64 bit.

**Error**

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 178 of C:/server/httpd/Apache24
/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:\\server\\php\\php5apache2_4.dll into 
server: The specified module could not be found.
```

**code which causes**

```
LoadModule php5_module C:\server\php\php5apache2_4.dll  ----> This Line

<IfModule php5_module>
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
 PHPIniDir "C:\server\php"
</IfModule>
```

It was worked earlier - I just put a new OS and trying the same under `C;\server` for generic setup so that I can make use of it in every windows 64 bit system with same directory structure.

**My doubt** : Is it due to version incompatible problems

**Download locations:**

```
 mysql is from mysql domain
 php from php domain
 apache from apachelongue
```

Please help me to solve the error.

**EDIT FOR A COMMENT:**

php apache dll is present in the php directory

**A NOTE**

A question becomes stupid when you know the answer like you remember `a-z`. So no question is stupid generally.

Comment: im sure its a stupid question but you can verify the file `C:\\server\\php\\php5apache2_4.dll` is there right ?

Comment: Hello @Pogrindis , Its there. I have that much knowledge to check.

Comment: have you tried to change *C:\server\php\php5apache2_4.dll* into **C:\\server\\php\\php5apache2_4.dll** or **C:/server/php/php5apache2_4.dll**

Comment: also just note this is related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263297/cannot-load-php5apache2-2-dll though older apache version (2.2) but same error.

Comment: @donald123, Yes I tried with your one before posting this question. It is not a problem. It automatically converts to `\\\`

Comment: Goops, did you download the threaded version ??

Comment: @Pogrindis - Yes Thread safe one. I have modifed my extension_dir to point my php extension

Comment: can i ask you a stupid question, why didn't you use https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html .. when i understand you, you want to *copy* the folder to another windows-machine and use it ... xampp provides this

Comment: I want to play with separate components. I have read `one of SO threads` - A user who has more reputation said that `you can have cntrollability more with this[my] design` than `xampp`

Comment: @donald123 - for your first question - [refer this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down)

Comment: Which build from the apachelounge site did you use? There are VC14,VC11,VC10 builds for both x86 and x64. Same question for php (plus thread safe or non thread safe, though I believe the nts version doesn't contain a php5apache2_4.dll)

Comment: @VolkerK - `php-5.6.11-Win32-VC11-x64 , httpd-2.4.16-win64-VC14` - It's a thread safe one. `php apache dll` is present under php directory

Comment: You did install the VC14 redistributables for the httpd.exe (otherwise it would have been another error mesage ;-)) But did you also install the VC11 redists for the php.dll ?

Comment: @VolkerK - So it is version incompatible. right? These are the files I used buddy

Comment: The VC11 php.dll from php.net is working with the VC14 build from apachelounge. But afaik you need to install both redistributables, those for VC14 _and_ VC11. Did you do that? If not, just try it. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: In my installed program list, I have redistributable for 2005, 2008, 2010, 2013, 2015. Let me try

Comment: In this [link](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/), they mentioned that I need VC15. I have it.[php](http://windows.php.net/download/) requires vc12. is it the problem @VolkerK

Comment: No, it requires VC11, Visual C++ 11 == Visual Studio 2012 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [VC14 (Visual Studio 2015) build of the httpd.exe from apachelounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC14/) in combination with the VC11 (Visual Studio 2012) [builds of php from php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/) you have to install the C runtimes for both versions.

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC14/ says:

> Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC : [vc_redist_x64/86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46881)

http://windows.php.net/download/ says:

> - The VC11 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 [x86 or x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed

The automagically created import code for [implicitly linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx) to the CRT in an application gives you a message box that complains about the missing redistributables. But in this case a .dll is missing another import. And to get this (specific) information propagated is a bit more complicated....
So, without tools like e.g. [Depedency Walker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256872) you're stuck with the generic `Cannot load yaddayadda.dll into server`.